# Kivy: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind' when accessing list object

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am building a Kivy app with multiple screens. One of these screens builds a list that I will pass to other functions that will display the result on another screen. One of the screens in my .py file contains the method get_items():

```
class Menu(Screen):
    def get_items(self):
        return self._items
```

self._items is a list that is also initialized and modified depending on user action in this class. All of this works, and I can print self._items in the terminal. However, what I need to do is pass this list to another screen, and I achieve this my turning self._items into a list that is accessible everywhere in the app (I have a button on the Menu screen that does this when pressed):

```
Button:
    on_press:
        app.itemlist = root.get_items()
```

So what I think has happened is that I have assigned the list self._items to an object app.itemlist via the function get_items(). And I have verified that app.itemlist is indeed still a list, and I can print it and its length to the terminal via other screens. However, I cannot, for example make it the text of a Label, even if I convert it to a string. For example,

```
Button:
    text: str(app.itemlist)
```

returns the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'`. If I pass itemlist to a function that returns a string (which is ultimately what I want to do), I get the same error. I've been stuck on this for quite a while - any help here would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

main.py:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from snartoolsmod import *

Builder.load_file("snartools.kv")

class DiningButton(Button):
    pass

class DirectionButton(Button):
    pass

class ItemButton(Button):
    pass

class SubmenuButton(Button):
    pass

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class WhitmansMenu(Screen):

    def initialize_list(self):
        itemList = Menu('whitmans')
        global allItems
        allItems = itemList.getCopy()
        return itemList

    def modify_list(self, itemList, value, dish):
        if value == 'down':
            for item in itemList:
                if dish == item.getDish():
                    itemList.remove(item)
                    break
        else:
            for item in allItems:
                if dish == item.getDish():
                    itemList.append(item)
                    break

    def modify_state(self, value, submenu, length):
        if value == 'down':
            for i in range(1, length+1):
                button = self.ids[str(submenu)+'_item'+str(i)]
                button.state = 'down'
        else:
            for i in range(1, length+1):
                button = self.ids[str(submenu)+'_item'+str(i)]
                button.state = 'normal'

class ToolScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ToolButton(Button):
    pass

class InstructionsLabel(Label):
    pass

class SubLabel(Label):
    pass

class LengthExact(Screen):

    def get_list(self, itemList):
        return itemList

class LengthRange(Screen):
    pass

class PriceExact(Screen):
    pass

class PriceRange(Screen):
    pass

class MoreExact(Screen):
    pass

class MoreRange(Screen):
    pass

screen_manager = ScreenManager()
screen_manager.add_widget(HomeScreen(name="home_screen"))
screen_manager.add_widget(WhitmansMenu(name="whitmans_menu"))
screen_manager.add_widget(ToolScreen(name="tool_screen"))
screen_manager.add_widget(LengthExact(name="length_exact"))
screen_manager.add_widget(LengthRange(name="length_range"))
screen_manager.add_widget(PriceExact(name="price_exact"))
screen_manager.add_widget(PriceRange(name="price_range"))
screen_manager.add_widget(MoreExact(name="more_exact"))
screen_manager.add_widget(MoreRange(name="more_range"))

class SnartoolsApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return screen_manager

app = SnartoolsApp()
app.run()
```

.kv file (just the essential parts - it's quite long):

```
<WhitmansMenu>:
    on_enter: app.itemList = root.initialize_list()
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        DirectionButton:
            text: "Back"
            pos_hint: {'left': 1, 'top': 1}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                root.manager.current = "home_screen"
        DirectionButton:
            text: "Done"
            pos_hint: {'right': 1, 'top': 1}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                root.manager.current = "tool_screen"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.86}
        InstructionsLabel:
            text: "Select all menus and items to exclude from your order"
        ScrollView:
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                padding: 20
                spacing: 5
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                SubmenuButton:
                    id: fryer
                    text: 'Fryer'
                    on_state: root.modify_state(fryer.state, 'fryer', 7)
                ItemButton:
                    id: fryer_item1
                    text: 'Fried Green Beans'
                    on_state: root.modify_list(app.itemList, fryer_item1.state, 'Fried Green Beans')
                # A bunch more buttons below...
<LengthExact>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        DirectionButton:
            text: "Back"
            pos_hint: {'left': 1, 'top': 1}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                root.manager.current = "tool_screen"
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        pos_hint: {'top': 0.86}
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            InstructionsLabel:
                text: "Enter the number of items you want to order"
            SubLabel:
                text: root.get_list(str(app.itemList))
```

The Item and Menu classes seen above are defined in another .py file:

```
class Item(object):
    __slots__ = ["_canteen", "_submenu", "_dish", "_price"]

    def __init__(self, canteen, submenu, dish, price):
        self._canteen = canteen
        self._submenu = submenu
        self._dish = dish
        self._price = float(price)

    def getCanteen(self):
        return self._canteen

    def getSubmenu(self):
        return self._submenu

    def getDish(self):
        return self._dish

    def getPrice(self):
        return self._price

    def __len__(self):
        return 1

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self._dish == other._dish) and \
               (self._price == other._price)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Item({0},{1},{2},{3})".format(self._canteen, self._submenu, self._dish, self._price)

    def __str__(self):
        return "<{0},{1},{2},{3}>".format(self._canteen, self._submenu, self._dish, self._price)


class Menu(object):
    __slots__ = ["_canteen", "_result"]

    def __init__(self, canteen):
        self._canteen = canteen
        self._result = []
        with open(self._canteen + '.csv', 'r') as f:
            csvr = csv.reader(f)
            for row in csvr:
                item = Item(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3])
                self._result.append(item)

    def getCanteen(self):
        return self._canteen

    def getSubmenus(self):
        submenus = []
        for item in self._result:
            if item._submenu not in submenus:
                submenus.append(item._submenu)
        return submenus

    def getDishes(self):
        dishes = []
        for item in self._result:
            dishes.append(item._dish)
        return dishes

    def getPrices(self):
        prices = []
        for item in self._result:
            if item._price not in prices:
                prices.append(item._price)
        return prices

    def specifySubmenus(self, submenus):
        items = []
        for item in self._result:
            if item._submenu in submenus:
                items.append(item)
        self._result = items

    def sortMenu(self):
        return sorted(self._result, key=lambda x: x._price)

    def longestOrder(self, price):
        sortedMenu = self.sortMenu()
        minPrice = sortedMenu[0]._price
        return int(price / minPrice)

    def shortestOrder(self, price):
        sortedMenu = self.sortMenu()
        maxPrice = sortedMenu[-1]._price
        return int(price / maxPrice)

    def longOrder(self, price, sortedMenu=None):
        if sortedMenu == None:
            sortedMenu = self.sortMenu()
        sum = 0
        order = []
        for item in sortedMenu:
            if sum + item._price <= price:
                order.append(item._dish)
                sum += item._price
        return order

    def lengthExact(self, length):
        orders = []
        maxLen = len(self.longOrder(7))
        assert length == int(length) and 0 < length <= maxLen
        sortedMenu = self.sortMenu()
        maxPrice = 7 - (length - 1) * sortedMenu[0]._price
        for item in sortedMenu:
            if item._price > maxPrice:
                sortedMenu.remove(item)
        allCombos = list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(sortedMenu, length))
        for combo in allCombos:
            sum = 0
            for item in combo:
                sum += item._price
            if sum <= 7:
                orders.append(combo)
        return orders

    def lengthRange(self, lower, upper):
        allCombos = []
        orders = []
        maxLen = self.longestOrder(7)
        assert lower == int(lower) and upper == int(upper) and 0 < lower < upper <= maxLen
        sortedMenu = self.sortMenu()
        for i in range(lower, upper + 1):
            maxPrice = 7 - (i - 1) * sortedMenu[0]._price
            for item in sortedMenu:
                if item._price > maxPrice:
                    sortedMenu.remove(item)
            allCombos += list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(sortedMenu, i))
        for combo in allCombos:
            sum = 0
            for item in combo:
                sum += item._price
            if sum <= 7:
                orders.append(combo)
        return orders

    def priceExact(self, price):
        allCombos = []
        orders = []
        assert 0 < price <= 7
        sortedMenu = self.sortMenu()
        cheapestPrice = sortedMenu[0]._price
        maxLen = self.longestOrder(price)
        minLen = self.shortestOrder(price)
        for i in range(minLen, maxLen + 1):
            if i == 1:
                for item in self._result:
                    if item._price == price:
                        sortedMenu.remove(item)
            else:
                maxPrice = price - (i - 1) * cheapestPrice
                for item in sortedMenu:
                    if item._price > maxPrice:
                        sortedMenu.remove(item)
                allCombos += list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(sortedMenu, i))
        for combo in allCombos:
            sum = 0
            for item in combo:
                sum += item._price
            if sum == price:
                orders.append(combo)
        return orders

    def priceRange(self, lower, upper):
        allCombos = []
        orders = []
        assert 0 < lower <= upper <= 7
        sortedMenu = self.sortMenu()
        cheapestPrice = sortedMenu[0]._price
        maxLen = self.longestOrder(upper)
        minLen = self.shortestOrder(upper)
        for i in range(minLen, maxLen + 1):
            if i == 1:
                for item in self._result:
                    if item._price >= lower and item._price <= upper:
                        orders.append(item)
            else:
                maxPrice = upper - (i - 1) * cheapestPrice
                for item in sortedMenu:
                    if item._price > maxPrice:
                        sortedMenu.remove(item)
                allCombos += list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(sortedMenu, i))
        for combo in allCombos:
            sum = 0
            for item in combo:
                sum += item._price
            if sum >= lower and sum <= upper:
                orders.append(combo)
        return orders

    def moreExact(self, order, price):
        orderPrice = 0
        for item in self._result:
            if item._dish in order:
                orderPrice += item._price
        assert orderPrice <= price <= 7
        remaining = price - orderPrice
        return self.priceExact(remaining)

    def moreRange(self, order, lower, upper):
        orderPrice = 0
        for item in self._result:
            if item._dish in order:
                orderPrice += item._price
        assert lower < upper <= 7 and orderPrice < upper
        low = lower - orderPrice
        high = upper - orderPrice
        return self.priceRange(low, high)

    def append(self, value):
        return self._result.append(value)

    def remove(self, value):
        return self._result.remove(value)

    def getCopy(self):
        return self._result.copy()

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._result)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._result)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Menu({})".format(self._result)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self._result)
```

Comment: Try creating a ListProperty named `itemlist` in your App beforehand. Also, post the full code, it will be easier for me to help you that way.

Comment: Thank you for your willingness to help me on this. I have posted probably more code than is needed, but it should be everything required to spot the error. To summarize, there is main.py, my .kv file, and another .py file which defines the 'Item' and 'Menu' classes used in the main.py file. The error occurs on the last line of the .kv file. As you can see, I am trying to set the text of a label to the string representation of 'itemList', which is constructed in the 'WhitmansMenu' screen and called via 'app.itemList'. Again, the error is: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this seems to work:
https://pastebin.com/A2hEKHLx

When kivy tries to get your app automatically from the .kv file, it uses `App.get_running_app()` function. For some reason, it returned None. I did it manually in the `LengthExact` class, take a look. I also added a default value of `[]` for the `itemList`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this fixes the issue. Like you say, it just returns a black screen. Do you need me to clarify any part of the code?

Comment: Agh, sorry. I'll edit my answer with a link to pastebin code. It seems to work now. I'm not sure why kivy couldn't do `App.get_running_app()` properly from .kv file.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue! I accepted the answer, however it seems to have created a secondary problem - but I think we're very close. For some reason, when I click on the buttons on the WhitmansMenu page (these are toggle buttons, btw) they no longer stay in the 'down' position. I added a print statement in the .kv file under `<WhitmansMenu>` and noticed that `app.itemList` actually returns two copies of the desired list. (under `on_enter:`, I typed `print(app.itemList)`). Any idea what's going wrong? Thanks again.